# Lua binary networking

Tags: networking, lua, coronasdk

Trying to create network game using Corona SDK, but have some troubles with lua sockets.
At first I used tcp and json data, but now remaking to udp and binary data.

How can I send custom structure to server?

For example, I need to send code of operation (short), ID (long) and two coordinates (float).
I can do that with C or Java, but don't understand how to do that with Lua, how to write it into socket?

Comment: I was thinking of suggesting a generic solution using any of the lua implementations of google protocol buffers, but even the [most lua-pure](https://github.com/Neopallium/lua-pb) depends on LPeg, which you have to compile from C. And that I don't know if you can do with Corona SDK

Answer (score 2):

There is [lpack](http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/#lpack) library if you want to stick with a binary representation for you data (it works similar to Perl pack/unpack methods if you are familiar with those). Another option is [struct](http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~roberto/struct/) library that packs data to/from C struct format.

There is also a variety of [serializers](http://lua-users.org/wiki/TableSerialization); I wrote [Serpent](http://notebook.kulchenko.com/programming/serpent-lua-serializer-pretty-printer) precisely for the purpose of sending Lua data over sockets.

In either case you will end up with a string that represents your (packed) data. You just send this string using regular send/receive calls ([TCP](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/tcp.html) and [UDP](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/udp.html)).

Comment: One caveat specific to Corona SDK: most serializers rely on using `loadstring` to deserialize the encoded data and this won't work with Corona as it doesn't make `loadstring` available.

Answer (score 0):

In the most general sense, you *don't.* Lua is not a low-level language; it doesn't have a way to pretend that an integer or float are a bag of bits that it can just shove down a pipe.

If you need to send non-textual data, then Lua's probably not your best bet here. However (depending on what Corona lets you do), you could write a function in C that takes some Lua values, packages them up for shipping, and returns a Lua string that Lua can hand off to LuaSockets. This "string" will be transmitted as a byte array, not a human-readable string.